# c#: Creating a 10x10 field (and array) of CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I have a problem, and i don't know why but i can't figure out what it actually is.

All I want to do is create a 10 x 10 field of checkboxes as a board for a game basically.

The thing I came up with should use an Array of these boxes to easily identify them from box[0,0] to box[9,9] according to theirt coordinates in the field.

This is the code i am struggling with:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // == OPTIONS ========================================
        int xpos = 60;  // Position of the first Checkbox (x)
        int ypos = 60;  // Position of the first Checkbox (y)

        int size = 10;  // Number of Rows and Columns

        int spc = 30;   // Space between boxes (Default:20)
        // ====================================================

        //other Variables
        int x, y;


        //Creating the Game Field
        CheckBox[,] box = new CheckBox[size,size];


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {

                box[i, j] = new CheckBox();

                //For Debugging Purpuses: Showing i and j next to checkBox
                box[i, j].Text = i + "" + j;

                //Set Position
                y = i * spc + xpos;
                x = j * spc + ypos;
                box[i, j].Location = new Point(x,y);

                this.Controls.Add(box[i, j]);
            }
        }

    }
```

All I get from this is one single column of checkboxes marked [0,0] to [0,9].

And even if i switch around x and y or i and j, that never changes. So i.E. i will never get a row of checkboxes, just always a single column. Where am I going wrong with this?

i just get those 10 checkboxes, nothing more. they do not seem to be placed over each other either.

Hope you can help me out here :) thanks.
timo.

Comment: If it is a 10 times 10 field, you will have checkboxes from box[0,0] to box[9,9], not "from box[0,0] to box[10,10]".

Comment: You also need to take into account the width & height of a checkbox. Did you try to debug it in order to see where the values are not correctly calculated? I don't think you need to go over a total of 100 checkboxes to find out where the bug is...

Comment: Did you debug the code? Set a breakpoint on the last line and check how many controls there are in this.Controls. If its HTML, check the source code of the generated html to check for the checkboxes.

Comment: By the way, knowing which GUI toolkit you are using may have been a more valuable addition to the question tags than *checkbox* (it is most probably WinForms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check-boxes are too wide by default.

Try it with (for example):

```
int spc = 50;
```

And also add this in the loop:

```
box[i, j].Width = 40;
```

Comment: that was it, i did remove the part where it labels the boxes, added the line to change the width of a box to 20 and then it worked with spc=20 aswell..  thank you very much for your help